# Correctly configure the JavaScript tools

Tags: 8, javascript, nodejs

I am trying to configure eslint for Drupal in `PHPStorm`, and it's really confusing.

For example, I have installed the node dependencies that comes in the `web/core/package.json` file. In `PHPStorm`, in the Eslint settings, I have configured web/core/node_modules/eslint, but with this module `(eslint-config-drupal)`, I don't know if to configure it `with node_modules/eslint` which is in the root where I installed `eslint-config-drupal`. The same goes for prettier.

When I check the Drupal JavaScript coding standards using, for example, `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --no-ignore "../modules/custom/my_module/js/file.js"` I had to pass the `--no-ignore` parameter in order to see the style errors.

The `package.json` used by Drupal core has some interesting commands that I am interested in using, such as `transpiling ES6 to ES5`. What the core does is transpile a file.es6.js file to file.js.

In the Drupal documentation I see that the command can apparently be used like `npm run build:js -- --file ../modules/custom/my_module/js/file.es6.js`, but when I do so, I notice That the Babel plugins don't process them and only show the same file. I only added a generic header text.

I understand that these commands are for the Drupal core, and if I temporarily copy a `file.es6.js` file to a location within the core, Babel transpiles it correctly.

The only way I have managed to transpile it is to copy the `package.json` file, the core JavaScript files, and use it in the root of the project. What I don't like is having everything duplicated.

I don't know if there is a way to use what comes with Drupal core in a transparent way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Starting with Drupal 10, an ES6 build process will no longer be used, and several of the scripts related to these tasks are removed.

Now Js code will be written directly without an intermediate compilation process.